# Meaning of "common PC" or "garden PC"

Tags: definitions

I've recently started reading about IOT. One of the terms that I've come across (with respect to prototyping IOT-enabled device) is "common PCs"/ "garden PCs". I am unsure if this refers to basic computer categories such as laptops and personal computers or if this is a completely different device altogether.

While browsing for explanations, I did come across this link talking about green PCs: https://www.techopedia.com/definition/2111/green-personal-computer-green-pc

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean "garden variety PC"? There are no strict definitions of these categories; they're mostly just marketing terms and really have nothing to do with IoT.

Comment: The book that I'm referring to simply says "garden PC"; however, based on your explanation, I believe "garden variety PC" would make sense here. If I apply this to the context described in the book, they're probably referring to computers in general. Thanks a ton for clarifying this.